# sscanf: Reading in a value for a char

Tags: c

Is there a way to use sscanf `%c` to read in the value of a `char`? How would I put in the escape sequence for unicode or ascii for a particular character?

```
sscanf("%c",chr);
```

Comment: What do you mean by the value of a char ? and what is this escape sequence for a char ?

Comment: You need to use `scanf()` to read `stdin`. `sscanf()` uses a `const char*` as its input, and you need to pass the address of `chr`: `scanf("%c", &chr);`.

Comment: @Minion91, I mean specify the ASCII code or Unicode value in the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read a character from the input with

```
 char chr;
 scanf ("%c", &chr);
```

Reading escape sequences can be operating system specific.  On most you would have to tell the terminal driver to not process escape sequences into other actions (like input line editing) and instead pass the raw characters through.  Once that is set, then you can repeat the above sequence for each character.